# Port missing in request object while testing with pytest in Flask

Tags: python, flask, request, pytest

I have created a very basic flask application **without** using app factory.

The folder structure of the application:

```
|__api
     |__templates
     |__tests     
        └── __init__.py
        └── conftest.py
        └── test_var.py
     |__utils
     |__database.py
     |__models.py
|__index.py
```

`database.py` looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI")
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

and the `index.py`looks like this:

```py
from flask import request

from api.database import app

@app.route("/")
def home():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")
```

I am importing the `app` from `database.py` to a fixture in `conftest.py`:

```py
import pytest
from database import app

@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
```

And my `test_var.py` looks like this:

```py
def test_home(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    print(response.__dict__)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

When I run `pytest`, I get the following error:

```bash
<WrapperTestResponse streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>
{'_charset': 'utf-8', 'headers': Headers([('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), ('Content-Length', '207')]), '_status': '404 NOT FOUND', '_status_code': 404, 'direct_passthrough': False, '_on_close': [], 'response': <werkzeug.wsgi.ClosingIterator object at 0x7f1649ad6d50>, 'request': <Request 'http://localhost/' [GET]>, 'history': (), '_compat_tuple': (<werkzeug.wsgi.ClosingIterator object at 0x7f1649ad6d50>, '404 NOT FOUND', Headers([('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), ('Content-Length', '207')])), 'json_module': <flask.json.provider.DefaultJSONProvider object at 0x7f16494d4590>}
```

Interestingly, the request object is: `<Request 'http://localhost/' [GET]>`, No port is defined in the request object.

I tried to follow many blogs and documentations on this, but couldn't find a solution.
Most of them have used `create_app()`.

But my project is already deployed on `vercel`, so is there a way to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: The value of `request.response` is expected (you're using a test client; there isn't really any port).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a 404 error because you never import `index.py`. Your `conftest.py` has:

```
from api.database import app
```

But that's an application with no routes. You can verify that by sticking a `breakpoint()` in your test function and examining `client.application.url_map`, which will show you:

```
(Pdb) p client.application.url_map
Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> static>])
```

The solution is to ensure you import `index.py`. E.g., make your `conftest.py` look like:

```
import pytest
from index import app

@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
```

After which we see:

```
(Pdb) p client.application.url_map
Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> static>,
 <Rule '/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> home>])
```